# Mule component class throws NoSuchMethodException on constructor

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a mule flow that is breaking because of an updated class.

Here's how I access the component in the mule flow.

```
  <jersey:resources doc:name="MyClass1">
    <componen   class="com.package.MyClass" />
                                </jersey:resources>
```

Earlier `MyClass1` had only a default constructor. Now, it has two constructors, one -without parameters( to replace the default) and one with parameters( for testing)

```
MyClass() {
  // some network access. 
}
```

and

```
 MyClass(int a , int b)
    {
    }
```

Here's my stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: could not find constructor on class: class com.package.MyClass, with matching arg params: 
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:467) ~[mule-core-3.6.0-M2.jar:3.6.0-M2]
    at org.mule.object.AbstractObjectFactory.getInstance(AbstractObjectFactory.java:132) ~[mule-core-3.6.0-M2.ja
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your class with Spring, using the appropriate constructor, then refer to it as a Jersey resource:

```
<jersey:resources>
  <spring-object bean="restService" />
</jersey:resources>
```